# List all items in a folder

Tags: php, html

I want to write a php script, which lists all the items in the folder, where the php script is located/in the folder where it was started (except index.php)...

I got 2 Problems

```
1. ATM it is only listing the items in the folder "foobar"<br/>
2. It is not creating a new `<li>` Tag for every new items<br/>
```

This is my code so far...

```
<?php

$folder = openDir("foobar");

while ($file = readDir($folder)) {

 if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

  echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>nothing</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />
</head>
<body>

<div id=\"title\">
<h1>nothing</h1>
</div>

<div id=\"main\">
<ul>
    <li><a href=\"foobar/$file\">$file</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>";
 }
}

closeDir($folder);
?>
```

Comment: Are you aware that if you have 100 files your are creating 100 HTML documents and concatenating them in the same file?

Comment: Are you trying to list all the files in one html document?

Comment: Yes I am trying to list alle the files in one html document and no I am not aware of this @Álvaro G. Vicario Oo are you kidding me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>nothing</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
        <h1>nothing</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <ul>
<?php
$folder = openDir(__DIR__);
while ($file = readDir($folder)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != "style.css") {
        echo "<li><a href=\"foobar/$file\">$file</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx this one works great just one little newbie question: What do I have to fill in by __DIR__, when I want to see the files in the directory where the php script is started?

Comment: `__DIR__` will be automatically replaced with the directory of the current file (see the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)).

Comment: I get the following error "Warning: opendir(__DIR__) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /www/nothing/index.php on line 17" "Warning: readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource in /www/nothing/index.php on line 18"

Comment: Ah "if ( !defined('__DIR__') ) define('__DIR__', dirname(__FILE__));" helps

Comment: And is there any way to exclude the files (index.php and style.css)?

Comment: Not `DIR`, use `__DIR__` (with two underlines before and after)! I have updated the `if` (see code above) to exclude both files.

Answer (score 0):

I if you are trying to list all the files in one html document, wrap in "`if`(){}" only `<li>` items